# Define name space in DRF routes

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to define a custom namespace for DRF routes.

Let suppose I have following route.

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
```

Now if I want to define name space like user-create, add-new-user, update-user, delete-a-user. Then how can I do this?

Comment: See *custom dynamic routers*: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#example

Comment: But as you can see, it adds already suffixes: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L105

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks